# launch modal with dynamically added button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to trigger modal with dynamically added button, but click event does not work.

here is a code sample that I use to add button within a table with jquery

```
var button = "<button data-original-title='View' type='submit' data-hover='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#properties" + property['_id'] + "' class='btn btn-default'><img src='images/home-icon.svg' height='20' width='20'></button>"
```

the script below works when I want to launch alert but did not figure out how to trigger modal

```
$('body').on('click', '#properties-table td:last-of-type button', function(){
   alert('fdsfasdf')
})
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @Harry Bomrah v3.3.5

Comment: Can you show us the modal div code ? I have setup a dummy jsfiddle, and your code works, Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/p3q9bmf5/

Comment: @Himanshu Tyagi hi I see your code works and I tested my code with your simple test modal and still does not work so the problem goes much deeper :(

Comment: post your entire related code fragment. Including html.

Comment: it's not that simple, we have 800 lines of code in script all related to this datatable and several modals, add, edit, delete....

Answer (score 0):

Your code wont work because you add the button after bootstrap has bind all its event. Thus while bootstrap is adding event listeners, it doesn't find your button and thus no event is attached. I advice you to use a js approach to launch modal.

**In your JS**

```
$('body').on('click', '#properties-table td:last-of-type button', function(){
  $($(this).data("target")).modal("show");
}
```

This should work. I have updated @Himanshu Tyagi fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p3q9bmf5/1/

Comment: I understand you and I see that your code works, but when I try it for those records that are added on page load modal opens and closes immediately and for dynamically added ones it still does not work. that said, there is something seriously wrong with our code and will need much deeper analysis